# San Basics: HBA vs. Controller?

Tags: controller, san

Basic SAN question:

If I'm building a SAN, each HBA card acts as the connection from a given server to the SAN.  Got it.  I want to build a single SAN with no single point of failure, so I need two switches, two controllers, and an external disks enclosure.  Okay.  I've got all that.  My question is that the two controllers are two components between the switch and the external disks enclosure, right?  In other words, I have to buy two components that are not the switches, HBAs, and the actual enclosure, right?

Comment: For the record, I've searched this on google thoroughly, and the results have me thoroughly confused.

Comment: I think you might be on the wrong venue.  I'd try over at http://serverfault.com/.  StackOverflow is for programming questions, and yours is about hardware.

Comment: Thanks.  I've read extensively about programming here and just assumed it was a general tech forum.  Thanks mate! :D

Answer (score 0):

Per you setting:
One or more servers with at least two FC ports. 
one or two FC switches.
one storage array with two controllers ( active/active or active/passitive)

Server FC port connect to Storage array FC port via FC switch.

Storage array create luns for server. switch setup zone ( connection and security)